# How to differentiate between the native Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V and the document level listeners added using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I have a Clipboard service in which I have a `copy()` and `paste()` methods which gets invoked whenever I do `Ctrl+C` & `Ctrl+V`. These are document level keyboard listeners which are added in a component using HostListeners. Now, whenever the user copies some text and does `Ctrl+V` my `paste()` method gets triggered which shouldn't happen. How can I prevent this from happening. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

My Clipboard Service:

```
export class ClipService {
    private srcFolder;
    private srcItem;

    constructor() {
    }

    copy(srcFolder, srcItem) {
        this.srcFolder = srcFolder;
        this.srcItem = srcItem;
    }

    paste(destFolder) {

    }

}
```

My component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'new-comp',
 templateUrl: 'new-comp.html'
})
export class NewComp {

constructor(private clipboard: ClipService){

}

private keydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
        let folder = this.folder.json;
        let item = folder.activeItem;
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 67) {
            this.clipboard.copy(folder, item);
        } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 86) {
             this.clipboard.paste(this.finder.activeFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Respective link https://codepen.io/jackocnr/pen/ezBKVQ will be helpful to you to achieve what you want.

Comment: If still above link doesn't help, try to post code that what you've accomplished till now.

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT I already have the event listeners in place and the functions trigger with the keyboard keys. I want to differentiate or intercept my functions when there is a browser native copy pastes are happening.

Comment: @Bergi any suggestions? :)

Comment: Donut, did you try Chellappan's answer?

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT That doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the keyboard events to handle the copy and paste. Simply use the clipboard events to handle them as follows:

```
@HostListener('document:copy', ['$event'])
copy(evt: ClipboardEvent) {
 let folder = this.folder.json;
 let item = folder.activeItem;
 this.clipboard.copy(folder, item);
}

@HostListener('document:paste', ['$event'])
paste(evt: ClipboardEvent) {
 this.clipboard.paste(this.finder.activeFolder);
}
```

Note: The Clipboard copy events are not supported in IE11.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger event in component level instead of using document level event

Trigger the copy paste method whenever yo do the copy paste in your component

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/host-level-click)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick($event)',
  }
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  onClick(e){
    console.log(1);
  }
}
```